# c++ Variable values not updated correctly on GUI

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I am debugging some simulation software that has been written partly in C++ and partly in Ada. On the GUI, there are two values displaying the ETA & TimeToGo of an entity moving in the simulation on any given leg of its journey, and for the remainder of the whole journey. The TimeToGo & ETA values that are displayed for the current leg are correct (i.e. how long it will take the entity to reach its current target destination from its current location). However, the TimeToGo & ETA values for the remainder of the whole journey are incorrect- approximately 40-50s lagging behind.

I have come across a couple of assignments in the code, and I am wondering if they are the wrong way round:

```
if(some condition){
    mFlightPlanData[0] = fpMiniToteData;
} else {
    mFlightPlanData[1] = fpMiniToteData;
}
```

`mFlightPlanData[]` is an array of `flightPlans`, of size 2- because each aircraft can have up to two flight plans at any one time- a primary and a secondary. `fpMiniToteData` is the variable used to display the flight plan data on the GUI.

Now, it appears to me that these assignments are the wrong way round- these seem to be saying:

> Set the first element in the flight plan array equal to the value of the display data
>
> > else
>
> Set the second element in the flight plan array equal to the value of the display data

However, what should be happening is that the `display data` should be being set to the value of either the first or second element in the `flight plan array`...

I tried to do this, by switching the assignments around, i.e.

```
if(some condition){
    fpMiniToteData = mFlightPlanData[0];
} else {
    fpMiniToteData = mFlightPlanData[1];
}
```

But I now get a compile error that says:

> error C2678: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const...' or there is no acceptable conversion)

What does this error mean? Do I need to have defined a function that will convert the data type held in the array to the data type of the `fpMiniToteData`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 12/02/2015 @ 1645**

`fpMiniToteData` is defined in the function definition- the function that the code above belongs to:

```
void FlightPlanInterface::setFlightPlanData(
     const FlightPlanMinitoteTypes::FlightPlanPerformanceDataViewId_Type viewId,
     const FlightPlanMinitoteTypes::FlightPlanMinitoteData_Variant& fpMiniToteData)
{
```

and `mFlightPlanData` is defined in a header file as follows:

```
private:
    FlightPlanMinitoteTypes::FlightPlanMinitoteData_Variant mFlightPlanData[2];
```

Comment: The error states that the variable `fpMiniToteData` is declared to be `const` - which makes assignments to it compilation errors.

Comment: you did not post enough for us to be able to help; the definition for  fpMiniToteData and mFlightPlanData would be useful, as well as knowing if the code you are showing is part of a function for which one or both of these are being passed in as parameters

Comment: Apologies- variable definitions added. @Barry - I tried removing the `const` keyword from the declaration, but that gave me an error stating: `overloaded member function not found in 'FlightPlanInterface'`....